# Why are all of my programs are closed when I SWITCH users without logging out

Tags: installed-programs

As stated, I'm not using suspend, and this is a desktop, so it's a simple user switch where the original user remains logged in in the background. When I switch back, all of my programs are automatically closed, including Unreal Engine, Discord, Blender, and more. This occurs for all four users. I have 32GB RAM, a Ryzen 7 and an RTX 2060, so I'm not running out of RAM. The Nvidia driver installed is the 535, and the 415 is not supported sadly.

Not really sure what's going on, and any help would be appreciated. Can provide logs at request, but I'm new to this and I'm not sure what to provide.